# How does an HTTP request reaches the web application inside an EC2 instance inside a VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I understand that EC2 instances inside a VPC network can have public IP address which can be used to connect to the outer internet. The Internet Gateway will replace the private IP of the instance with public IP before going out to the internet. My question is , how an end user initiated request ( type the URL of the web app installed inside the EC2 instance in the browser ) would reach the correct Internet Gateway so that the public IP of the EC2 instance could get translated to the private IP of the instance and the request is full filled? We have the public IP of the EC2 instance , but we have to go through the Internet Gateway in the VPC to reach the instance. Does the VPC have a public IP assigned as well ?

In [VPC Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Virtual_Private_Cloud), there is a sentence,

> Users are able to connect to the Internet by adding an Internet Gateway to their VPC, which assigns the VPC a public IPv4 Address.

In short how is the request fulfilled for a web app installed in an EC2 instance inside VPC?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: developer or administrator of the EC2 instance configures the list of the TCP/UDP ports which will be translated to the internal VPC address/ports.

Basically, everything you described is the thing called [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation), also it's not specific for HTTP only but can be used for any protocol.
Translation of the source address for all outgoing packets is called SNAT, the reverse process when the incoming packet's destination address is translated to some internal IP/port is known as DNAT.

Comment: >Short answer: developer or administrator of the EC2 instance configures the list of the TCP/UDP ports which will be translated to the internal VPC address/ports.

So, this has to be done in the instance profile?

Comment: > So, this has to be done in the instance profile?

Yes, IIRC AWS has all necessary routing and NAT already configured except all ports are filtered by the firewall. The only thing you need to do in the EC2 console is to create a security group for your instance and open ports your application uses.

Answer (score 0):

When you type the URL of the web app in the browser, there is something called DNS server will translate your domain into IP address.

In AWS, we have Route 53 service. You can register your domain there, add hosted zones and records so that your domain can be translated into correct IP address.

Comment: The resolved IP address points to EC2 instance public IP or some address related to VPC? We have the Internet Gateway through which the request needs to go before it reaches the instance inside.

Comment: The resolved IP address points to what depend on your records.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html
In the documents, IGW is not for the purpose you are writing. I think you want a proxy